# Fibonacci recursive

Tags: c

I'm trying to generate the x Fibonacci number.
I made a float function and I can't find why it's not working.
However, with an int function, it's working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float fib(float x) {
  if (!x)
    return 0;
  else if (x == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return fib(x - 2) + fib(x - 1);
}

int main() {
  float x, y;
  printf("x= ");
  scanf("%7.2f", &x);
  y = fib(x);
  printf("%7.2f", y);
  return 0;
}
```

error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x002C50D9 in Fibonacci.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00122F44).
```

Comment: Did you try to debug this?

Comment: For `float x` the `(!x)` does not have a boolean property.

Comment: Please compile with `-Wall`, your format string is malformed. Just use `scanf("%g", &x)`

Comment: Why do you use floating point numbers for a problem that involves strictly only integers?

Comment: If you want to extend the range you can use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`. Also please never use `float` unless there is a very good reason not to use `double` although I know many people are using obsolete teaching material.

Comment: @Ackdari thanks! I changed the %7.2f from scanf to %f.  Thank you all for help!

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just tried this one, I know normally we cand use int for fibonacci.

Comment: Edit the question to provide an [mre], particularly including the input that results in the error.

Comment: @Ayxan: Why would you think floating-point rounding is the issue? The operations used to control program flow (subtract one or two and comparing to zero or one) are all exact for integer values in the format commonly used for `float` up to 16,777,216, beyond where the `int` version would have also failed due to stack overflow in common environments with the default stack size (1-8 MiB for Windows, macOS, Linux).

Comment: @WeatherVane: `!` accepts operands of *scalar type*, which includes `float`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil it will be converted to `int`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because OP alleged that the same function with `int` instead of `float` works fine. Besides, a precise comparison of floating-point numbers is always wrong in my opinion, even if it works under some conditions.

Comment: @WeatherVane: C 2018 6.5.3.3 5 says “ The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type `int`. The expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.”

Comment: @Ayxan: (a) The reasoning that be because an `int` version works and a `float` version does not, the cause must be floating-point rounding is invalid. As stated, the arithmetic is exact, and the integer and floating-point operations would be identical for identical argument values to the function up 16,777,216. The cause of the error is more likely input of a non-integer numeral or `scanf` failure due to the improper conversion specifier.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Alright, I was wrong, thank you for correcting me. I'll delete my comment. What was the reason that `int` version worked, `float` version didn't then?

Comment: @Ayxan: Likely OP entered a non-integer numeral like “2.5” or the `scanf` did not assign any value to `x` because `%7.2f` is not a correct conversion specification for `scanf`.

Comment: Modify your program to print the return value of `scanf` and the full value of `x` (print using `%.99g`) after `scanf`. Update the question to show the resulting output.

Comment: @Foreastbtch: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

This recursive `float` version should use approximately the same stack space as the `int` version: proportional to the argument version.

There are multiple problems here:

- the `scanf` conversion format `"%7.2f"` is incorrect: the `.2` is meaningless and causes the conversion to fail. The `7` means at most 7 bytes should be read and converted as a `float`, probably not what you meant. You do not test the return value of `scanf()` so you don't realise that `x` stays uninitialized, so the code has undefined behavior anyway, but `x` is quite unlikely to be an integer. Use `%f` and check that `scanf()` returns `1`.
- if you give an argument that is too large, the function will recurse too deep and produce a **stack overflow**.
- if the argument is not an integer or negative, the termination tests will not stop the recursion: `if (!x) return 0; if (x == 1) return 1;`. If the initial argument is not an integer, subtracting 1 or 2 will keep producing numbers that are not integers and the tests will fail to stop the recursion as `x` passes into the negatives.

In both cases, the recursion continues and soon the stack space is exhausted anywhere between 100000 calls and a few million. Your CPU can perform hundreds of millions of calls per second so the **stack overflow** occurs almost immediately.

For other arguments, given the exponential nature of this recursion you are more likely to lose patience over execution time than to experience a **stack overflow**.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float fib(float x) {
    if (x > 200)
        return INFINITY;
    if (x <= 2)
        return 1;
    return fib(x - 2) + fib(x - 1);
}

int main() {
    float x, y;
    printf("x= ");
    if (scanf("%f", &x) == 1) {
        y = fib(x);
        printf("%7.2f\n", y);
    } else {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior of `.2` in a conversion specification for `scanf`. OP’s implementation may have not assigned any value to `x`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: good point. I forgot to fix that. The `.2` is meaningless and causes the conversion to fail, which is a better explanation for the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong scanf format.

```
int main() {
  float x, y;
  printf("x= ");
  scanf("%f", &x); //Your mistake was here!
  y = fib(x);
  printf("%7.2f", y);
  return 0;
}
```